# Get only Column Name and number of items in that column using Perl+MySQL(DBI)

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, dbi

I'm using LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, Perl). Using the DBI module from CPAN.

I'm trying to get COLUMN_NAME and COUNT at the same time, and store them into a Perl Hash.

so that I can print in HTML something like this:

```
Album: Selfies; #Column_Name
Photos: 0; #Count
```

For this I think I would need a for/foreach loop to print the key and corresponding value of the hash, one set at a time. I got the basics down as you see.. even successfully wrote 2 separate SQL statements, but I'm looking for a more efficient way. Also, there were some issues:

A. The first Column_Name/Count set was coming out as empty, though rest were fine. something like this.

```
Album: 
Photos:

Album: First
Photos: 2
```

B. In case of count being 0, It was returning blank line again, Something like:

```
Album: First_album
Photos:
```

C. To fix both, I tried to grep /^$/ .. but result was something like this:

```
Album: 1
Photos: 1
```

Pretty stuck at the moment. My questions are:

<strike>If there is a combined SQL statement to get COLUMN_NAME AND COUNT. I know how to prepare separate statements, but I hope there is a way to reduce it to one statement.</strike>

second question, I think the part I'm doing wrong is extracting the COLUMN_NAME is

```
$rv = $sth->fetchrow_array; #I think this is the wrong way maybe.
```

I tried the other things by looking at the DBI documentation, but so far, haven't figured out how to over come the first 2 problems above.

---

sample structure of MySQL database:

DB: Testing
Table: firsttable

columns: Selfies, Panaroma
Selfies contains 3 values, Panaroma contains 5 values.

I want to extract this information using DBI/Perl and present it, in the following manner:

```
Album: Selfies
Photos: 3

Album: Panaroma
Photos: 5
```

Sql statements

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name;
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
```

Comment: FYI, the P in LAMP stands for PHP, not Perl.

Comment: What is your query? Why don't you know the column name from the query?

Comment: Edited the question a bit at the end above. Also regarding LAMP, the P is generally PHP, that is why I described Perl clearly. @Barmer

Comment: Please show your SQL query. Also show some sample data and the result you're trying to get from it.

Comment: added the infos @Barmer

Comment: `COUNT(column_name)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`, unless there can be null values in the column. Did you mean `COUNT(DISTINCT column_name)`, so it doesn't count duplicates?

Comment: The 'P' in 'LAMP' has been used to stand for 'PHP', 'Python' and 'Perl'. None of these are more correct than the others.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're doing, this is the query:

```
SELECT "Selfies" AS Album, COUNT(DISTINCT Selfies) AS Photos
FROM table_name
UNION
SELECT "Panorama" AS Album, COUNT(DISTINCT Panorama) AS Photos
FROM table_name
```

Fetch the results and output them in a loop.

Comment: I will try this in few minutes.. will let you know asap.

Comment: This isn't what I need actually. I'm trying to list all columns in a table, as well as count the no of values in that column.

Comment: Why are columns being created like that? It seems like you're not normalizing your data properly. Dynamic data should be column values, not columns.

Comment: OK, so you need to perform a query against information_schema.columns. Get all the column names, and for each of them generate a subquery like the ones I wrote. Then join them all with `UNION` and execute that query.

Comment: somewhat yes. All column names in a given table, and no of values in each of those column. If I can do both these things in one single SQL statement, it would be really good.

Comment: You can't do it in a single SQL statement. SQL can't use variables for column names. So you have to do a separate query to create dynamic SQL.